# How to install both .net framework 4.6.1 and 4.6.2 on a server?

Tags: .net, frameworks, .net-framework-version

Ho do i install both the versions `4.6.1` and `4.6.2` on a server and target applications specifically to a specific version of .net framework?

Comment: .NET installs are cumulative: installing 4.6.2 includes 4.6.1. To designate the version for an application depends on the kind of application (ie. is version different for a ASP.NET web app vs. a console application).

Comment: The problem is that my web application code uses microsoft exception management block and the dlls are not compatible with framework 4.6.2. while i have to install 4.6.2 for the new application, i do not want the previous applications to crash. Event though I have target framework key in my web config. It seems to be no good.

Answer (score 2):

.NET 4.x installs are cumulative. Installing 4.6.2 will include 4.6.1, 4.6, 4.5.2, ….

To specify which version a specific web app uses, use the `<httpRuntime>` element in your web.config.

Eg. to target 4.6.1:

```
<system.web>
  …
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1"  />
  …
```

(This will cause the web app to fail to run with an unsupported framework exception if designated version is not available.)

For GUI and console executables the target version is in the manifest or `app.config` file.

Comment: I already have this key  `<compilation debug="false" defaultLanguage="c#" targetFramework="4.6.1">` in place

Comment: @DeepanshuKalra Please include *all* information in the question. Including an errors you are getting (startup errors are often detailed in the application event log).

Answer (score 1):

When you install 4.6.2, it replaces among others 4.6.1. Applications targeting 4.6.1 still will work.

See the installer notes:

> The Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6.2 is a highly compatible, in-place update to the Microsoft .NET Framework 4, 4.5, 4.5.1, 4.5.2, 4.6, and 4.6.1.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3151802/the-.net-framework-4.6.2-web-installer-for-windows

Comment: My code refers to dlls from the ExceptionManagementApplicationBlock to write any exceptions raised by the application to the EventVwr. Now these dlls are not compatible with framework 4.6.2. For framework 4.6.2 i am using Log4net which works fine.The servers need to be updated to 4.6.2. How do i get the previously deployed application to work on these servers?